# Servicestack RegistrationFeature Unable to bind request

Tags: c#, servicestack

I'm trying to get the RegistrationFeature to work alongside the twitter and facebook auth stuff. Twitter and Facebook are working but the RegistrationFeature doesn't seem to want to play ball.

Here is the response I get:

> response Status
>   error CodeRequestBindingExceptionmessageUnable to bind requeststack Trace at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.RestHandler.GetRequest(IHttpRequest httpReq, IRestPath restPath) at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.RestHandler.ProcessRequest(IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes, String operationName)

Here is the code I have in ConfigureAuth:

```
var appSettings = new AppSettings();

Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
    () =>
        new AuthUserSession(),
        new IAuthProvider[] {
        new CredentialsAuthProvider(),              
        new TwitterAuthProvider(appSettings),      
        new FacebookAuthProvider(appSettings),
        new GoogleOpenIdOAuthProvider(appSettings)
    }));


Plugins.Add(new RegistrationFeature());

var mongoClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://192.168.0.17");
var server = mongoClient.GetServer();
var db = server.GetDatabase("Sonatribe");

container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(c =>
    new MongoDBAuthRepository(db, true));
```

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

Happened to me also. Turned out it was the swagger that was not passing the integer because i had space inside my variable:

```
 [ApiMember(Name = " TrackingItemId", ......
```

(notice space before the variable!)